# What do we do with....?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, flagging

I've noticed the last couple of days, some seriously **broad** (*holding back from the actual word I want to use*) questions have been asked.

These question are ones that will most likely never get an answer. They also still have less than 5 "votes to close".

Personally I think they are a waste of space, so what would the best action be if they still don't have enough votes to be closed?

1. Flag the question to be deleted
2. Simply leave it and hope 5 votes are made eventually

Thoughts?

Comment: No need to flag them. They get pushed into the review queue when someone votes to close. Typically one of the moderators will actually go through the queue and be the deciding vote on them. All the ones that led you to ask this, I'm pretty sure I just closed.